# Excel Formula IF statement, make cell blank when other cell has value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet in Excel of which I want to check if a cell has been filled in with the string "x". If the value is "x" then I want the value in the cell of the formula to be empty/null.
So what I did was:

```
=IF(E5="x", "", "")
```

Now, when I hit enter, it says that there is a problem found with the formula and highlights the '"x",' part. How can I resolve this issue? I do not want to use vba!

Comment: I copied and pasted the formula you provided in a new workbook have no problem with it. That said, I imagine eventually you will change the formula so that something is displayed if the value is not `x`? Because right now the cell will always look blank so you may as well leave it empty

Comment: That's odd. Could it be as a result of the extension? Like I do work within a .xlsm file. And no, it has to be blank. The goal was that if one is filled in, the other is made blank.

Comment: @Redd Could you please post a screenshot where the formula is being highlighted?

Comment: File format shouldn't affect it. Right now if `E5` is filled in, then wherever you have the formula is blank and if it is *not* filled is, wherever you have the formula is also blank. Since it will *always* be blank, why bother with a formula?

Comment: You will get an error message if your separator is ***;*** rather than ***,***

Comment: Also it almost sounds like you are going to have two cells linked with formulas so only one can have `x` in it at a time.  If this is true, then formulas are not the way to go.  You will need vba.

Answer (score 0):

The formula has no problem.
looks like you want to replace x to "" inside the cell E5, then I would suggest
Select cell E5
Ctrl+F, click on "Replace"
enter x in "Find what:"
Click "Options>>"
check "Match case" and "Match entire cell contents"